# Reload or re-render activity with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I save data in my NewCar activity as bellow :

```js
saveData() {
    this.retrieveData;
    this.state.DBCarName.push(this.state.CarName)
    AsyncStorage.setItem('CAR',JSON.stringify(this.state.DBCarName));            
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}
```

And I retrieve it in order to display the DBCarName state in a text on my Home activity :

```js
componentWillMount(){
    this.retrieveData();  
}

retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
        const car= await AsyncStorage.getItem('CAR')
        this.setState({ DBCarName: JSON.parse(car) })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

But when I press on my button that executes saveData, I go back to the Home activity in its last rendering, which means  I need to reload the app to get the get the last data rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'willFocus'

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', (payload) => {
    this.retrieveData();
});
```

I used inside page's constructor.

This listener works when navigate NewCar screen even navigate with go back or android hardware back button

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.retrieveData();` method in `componentDidMount()` method :

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.retrieveData();
}
```

Comment: you mean isteand of componentWillMount ?

Comment: Yes instead of `componentWillMound()` @Noivy

Comment: This didn't do the job unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass the params during the navigate:

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate("routeName", {params})
```

then check the params inside the componentDidUpdate of the "routeName" check the `this.props.navigation.state.params`

or you need to use redux.

Comment: You mean passing params during navigate does update the activity

Comment: Using componentDidUpdate you can read the new params and use them how you need them. Triggering a render or updating a value with the new you just passed